# Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' ('No such file or directory')

Tags: bridge, debian, raspberry-pi, obfs4, obfs4proxy

Lately I have been trying to set up an obfs4 bridge on my RaspberryPi 3 (running Raspbian 9 (stretch) ) following the [official guide](https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/).
After setting up the torrc file to:

```
OrPort [PORT1]
SeverTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:[PORT2]
ExtORPort auto
ContactInfo [EMAIL]
Nickname [NAME]
ExitRelay 0
```

and changing `NoNewPrivileges=no` in `/lib/systemd/system/tor@default.service` and `/lib/systemd/system/tor@.service` prior to restarting the daemon and tor, as well as setting up the portforwarding for both ports in the router, the ORPort gets set up properly (is reachable using the [official tool](https://bridges.torproject.org/scan/)).

**But** every attempt trying to connect to the obfs4 port fails with:

`dial tcp [IP]:[Port2]: connect: connection refused`

Now looking at the log files `/etc/log/tor/log`, there is one warning about the obfs4proxy:

`[warn] Could not launch managed proxy executable at '/usr/bin/obfs4proxy' ('No such file or directory')`

The thing is, that the obfs4proxy file actually exists in the directory and trying to start it manually fails with:

`[ERROR]: obfs4proxy - must be run as a managed transport`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Any suggestions on how I can get the bridge up and running?

**EDIT:**

tor-version: 0.2.9.16-1 stable
obfs4proxy-version: 0.0.7-1 stable

Comment: The exact versions of the `tor` and `obfs4proxy` packages you have installed might be useful to know.

Comment: @womble Oups forgot that... Should be fixed now. Thanks a lot for the heads-up!